# XPM with "Switch Device" not working

Tags: experience-manager, 2013-sp1

I am trying to preview page content while selecting option "Switch Device" and then select any mobile device except "Desktop", for a small duration it display page content and after that screen display white. In the Fiddler I can see few 404 exception for below pages:

1. http://tridioncms.com/WebUI/Editors/DevicePreview/Proxy/search.php?src=dynamictest&uid=www557ab14cf1dbc2.56314489&vid=pid-nameadmin-test01&afdts=1434104142929&afdrid=6553594
2. http://tridioncms.com/img.php?www557ab14cf1dbc2.56314489
3. http://tridioncms.com/track.php?uid=www557ab14cf1dbc2.56314489&d=test.com&sr=1366x768

Please let me know what could be the issue?

---

Here more information: TridionCMS.com is the cms url and we are using .Net framework as delivery website. Looks like search.php or img.php or track.php are the pages Experience manager is using internally based on the fiddler logs I can see.

Comment: can you give a bit more detail on the setup of your CMS, XPM and website, am I correct in assuming that your CMS URL is http://tridioncms.com, and your website is using PHP? In that case it looks like some of the links are not correctly proxied, and thus they ointing to a non existant location, hence returning a 404. But please edit your question and supply a bit more detail and background information.